# If $|f(x)|\le \frac{1}{(1+|x|^2)^{\alpha/2}}$, why is true that $\|\nabla f\|_{\infty} \le c?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, upper-lower-bounds

Let $N>4$ and $2a>N$. Consider the function $f:\mathbb R^N\to\mathbb R$ be a function of class $C^2$ such that
$$|f(x)|\le \frac{1}{(1+|x|^2)^{\alpha/2}}.$$

Is it possible to use this information to deduce that there exists a constant $c>0$ such that
$$\|\nabla f\|_{\infty} \le c?$$

At calc class today, it was exhibited as an obvious thing while proving a theorem.

Could someone please help me understanding why is that true? If it is not, which extra assumption on $f$ could guarantee that $\|\nabla f\|_{\infty}\le c?$

I am a 2 year physics student and I am not so familiar with this kind of things. Thank you everyone.

Comment: It is an obviously wrong statement -: )

Comment: @geetha290krm thank you for the comment. Which assumption should be added to guarantee that $\|\nabla f\|_{\infty}\le c$? I apologize if that's dumb, but I feel a bit confused on these things.

Comment: Generally there is no way of bounding only $f$ in a way that the derivatives can't blow up. You can always add an arbitrarily small perturbation that has arbitrarily large gradients so that the bound is satisfied and the derivatives blow up.

Comment: A counterexample is $\cos(|x|^{2n})/(1+|x|^2)^{\alpha/2}$ with $n$ sufficiently large.